# JPA Error when using multiple ID generation strategies

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am using different Primary key generation strategies Identity, Sequences for different entities.

During insertion, the Sequences are working fine, but I am getting an error with the Identity saying

> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid object name
>   'mySchema.hibernate_sequence'.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mySequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mySequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "mySequence", allocationSize = 100, schema = "mySchema")
```

Comment: why would you use 2 different strategies on one class?

Comment: Its not for one class, for multiple classes one with Identity and the other with Sequence

Comment: so sequence works in one class, hence that is not part of the problem (and can be removed from the question), so just focus on the IDENTITY case. When you have a class with IDENTITY and you let your JPA provider create the schema does it generate the column correctly? then at runtime, what SQL is invoked with a persist?

Comment: schema is already created, and has PK defined as Identity in SQL server, I have hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = none. I see insert satements generated by hibernate as well, issue is it tries to  "select next value for myschema.hibernate_sequence", for PK even though its an Identity column

Comment: to be more specific this is the DML hibernate doing "insert into MY_TABLE (CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, ACCOUNT_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", there is a no primary here, but why does it issue  "select next value for myschema.hibernate_sequence"

Comment: Why not post the complete Entity in your question and then people may have a clue? With the JPA provider I use (DataNucleus) I have no issues with the situation you describe